# The named parameters are not defined

Tags: flutter

I'm creating a navigation app in flutter but the problem is that my dart analysis is showing error that itemCount and itemBuilder is not defined. I've also attached the picture link:

[image]

Comment: I had this same problem then I clicked the refresh Icon in the top right of "Dart Analysis" Tab and it went away